# How do I set System Path in my dockerfile for a Windows Container?

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, hyper-v

I am writing a Dockerfile to create a container for OpenJDK using the new, native docker support in Windows 10.  This is NOT using docker-toolbox.  I would like to set the system path to include the java path, but I can't figure out how.  I've tried several variations of the following file, but I can't get the path to set correctly.

```
FROM nanoserver:latest

RUN powershell -Command "Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force;Set-PSRepository -Name PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted;Install-Module PS7Zip;" 

ADD https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild/releases/download/1.8.0.91-3/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-3.b14.windows.x86_64.zip java.zip

RUN setx /M JRE_HOME C:\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-3.b14.windows.x86_64\jre
RUN setx /M JAVA_HOME C:\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-3.b14.windows.x86_64
RUN powershell -Command "Expand-7Zip java.zip"
RUN ["powershell", "$env:Path=$env:Path+\";C:\\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-3.b14.windows.x86_64\\bin\""]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this Golang sample has a crufty way to do this: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/blob/master/windows-container-samples/golang/Dockerfile#L24

Comment: `RUN powershell.exe -Command $path = $env:path + ';C:\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-3.b14.windows.x86_64\bin'; Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\' -Name Path -Value $path` Was the magic incantation.  Thanks for pointing out the golang dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Powershell does not allow modifying the system path variable using that method. The `$env:Path` gives read access to the system path, not write. Which means if you change `$env:Path` it will only affect your current PS environment.

See this link for a way to make changes to the system path variable: http://codingbee.net/tutorials/powershell/powershell-make-a-permanent-change-to-the-path-environment-variable/

Answer (score 0):

In case of windows container, you can do something like the below mentioned example within your docker file. Please make sure your windows image should have any such jdk/jre directory present at a location.

For me, I have been using the windows server core:ltsc2019 (***FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019***) which is customized with some wildfly config and jdk. But all in all the setx worked for me to set the java directly into the path.

Example:

> `RUN setx path "C:\jdk8u252-b09\bin"`

Answer (score 0):

The below commands worked for me in a `Dockerfile` with the base image `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019` for setting `Java` in the `PATH` env.

(Make sure to update `JAVA_HOME` with a valid path. It works even if there are spaces in the path.)

```
ENV JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17"

RUN $newPath = ('{0}\bin;{1}' -f $env:JAVA_HOME, $env:PATH); \
     [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $newPath, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)

CMD ["java", "--version"]
```